# Nominations Open for SDL Tridion MVPs

Tags: discussion

*Updated for 2015.*

We have an SDL-sponsored [community award for SDL Tridion knowledge online sharing](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/mvp_award/index.aspx), which thanks those that have shared their Tridion expertise.

Please consider **nominating individuals that have helped you or others online** that meet the [MVP criteria](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/mvp_award/index.aspx). Nominees accepted anytime, but we evaluate individual contributions between January and December.

> "To nominate an individual to the MVP Award, send an email to
>   `sdl.tridion.mvp` (at) `sdl.com` with the following information:
>
> - Nominee's **name**
> - Nominee's **email address**
> - Nominee's country (**where nominee lives/works**)
> - **Specific examples of why this nominee should be rewarded,** including relevant links to places where this nominee has shown his full potential, such as:
>
>   - Personal websites
>   - Community eXtensions
>   - Forum threads
>   - SDL Tridion Ideas website
>   - Social network sites"

*No nominations here, please. Though we need your help promoting the program, it's meant to thank and encourage online contributions!*

**Good luck to the nominees and thanks for sharing!**

*You can nominate SDL employees (who are eligible for an internal award) and self-nominations are okay if you worry no one's noticing your contributions.*

Finally, thanks to the managers, mentors, and other "enablers" that encourage and promote community participation. Especially as roles change and MVPs need to be less active, it's great having participation from colleagues of *MVP alumni*. :-)

Comment: Alvin, SDL employees are or are not eligible for nomination?

Comment: Yes, please nominate SDL employees that have shared this year. They're specifically eligible for an internal "Community Builder" award, though the focus is really about the larger community. I'll update the post and thanks for featuring it!

Comment: Is it worth opening a new question for this? Think it'll get pretty confusing with comments and answers about closing and reopening and rereopening and rerereclosing things...

Comment: Done: http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/q/402/46. I removed the extra comments as well.

Answer (score 5):

I'd just like to reinforce a couple of points.

Nominations are pretty much unconstrained. If you think someone deserves an award, please nominate them. You can not become an MVP unless there is a nomination. The committee only considers people who have been nominated (although, of course, the committee members are able to nominate too, so I hope we'd never miss a very obvious candidate).

Don't worry about whether the person is willing to accept an award. Recipients are asked privately whether they are prepared to accept, so no-one would ever get one if they didn't want it - so nominate away!!

A large part of the committee's work is in making sure that all or most of a given candidate's contributions are located and assessed. This is done by busy people at a busy time of year, so the more information that accompanies a nomination, the better. Having said that, don't let lack of details stop you nominating someone who should be considered. If you have more information later, you can always send a follow-up email with extra supporting information for your candidate.

Answer (score 3):

And... nominations for 2014 (recognising sharing in 2013) are closed!

We have received 40 nominations this year (up from 30 last year), which is awesome and reflects the growth of the community. The Selection Panel now starts the rather ungrateful task of selecting the best of those 40 to represent the SDL Tridion community in the coming year.

To all that participate in our community: Thank you!

Comment: Good luck to all

Comment: Btw, this was for nominations for the 2014 awards, which recognized sharing in 2013. I'm re-featuring the announcement for the next nominations. Time flies!