# Nominations Open for SDL Tridion MVPs 2016

Tags: discussion

As a follow-up to the [past reminders](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/46), SDL has sponsored an annual [community award for SDL Web (Tridion) knowledge online sharing](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/w/wiki/479.mvp-award-program) since 2009, for the 2010 award year.

Please consider **nominating individuals that have helped you or others online** that meet the [MVP criteria](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/w/wiki/479.mvp-award-program). Nominees are accepted anytime, but we evaluate individual contributions between January and December.

> "To nominate an individual to the MVP Award, send an email to
>   `sdl.tridion.mvp` (at) `sdl.com` with the following information:
>
> - Nominee's **name**
> - Nominee's **email address**
> - Nominee's country (**where nominee lives/works**)
> - **Specific examples of why this nominee should be rewarded,** including relevant links to places where this nominee has shown his full potential, such as:
>
>   - Personal websites
>   - Community extensions
>   - Forum threads (Tridion StackExchange)
>   - SDL Tridion Ideas website
>   - Social network sites"

*No nominations here, please.*

*You can nominate SDL employees (who are eligible for an internal award) and self-nominations are okay if you worry noone noticed your contributions.*

Not sure what this is about or want to reminisce? Let me plug my unofficial plugs for the program:

- [2011](http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/11/sdl-tridion-2011-mvp-retreat.html)
- [2012](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/01/congrats-new-sdl-tridion-mvps.html)
- [2013](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/01/welcome-new-sdl-tridion-community-mvps.html)
- [2014](http://www.createandbreak.net/2014/01/congrats-to-2014-sdl-tridion-community.html)
- [2015](http://www.createandbreak.net/2015/01/congratulations-to-sdl-tridion-mvp.html)
- [On selecting...](http://www.createandbreak.net/2015/01/selecting-community-winners.html)

Nominations accepted until December 31 for next year's award.

I'm looking forward to seeing how the seventh year in the award program goes. **Good luck to the nominees and thanks for sharing!**